# Direction of velocity confusion on inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, classical-mechanics

In Taylor's book *Classical Mechanics*, pg. 259, he works through the following example: Consider the following block and wedge system: The block ($m$) is free to slide on the wedge and the wedge (mass $M$) can slide on the horizontal table, both with negligible friction.[image: see picture here].

I am simply trying to write down the lagrangian in these generalized coordinates, but I run into a difficulty when he states the following: [image: picture]

What I don't get is why the $x$-component of velocity is $\dot{q_1} \cos(\alpha)+\dot{q_2}$. Shouldn't the answer be $\dot{q_1}\cos(\alpha)-\dot{q_2}$, since the $x$-components of $m$ will be in the positive $x$, and the $x$-component of velocity of $M$ will be in the negative $x$ direction?

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the two options:

Taylor's expression:
$$\dot{q_1} cos(\alpha)+\dot{q_2}$$

Your expression:
$$\dot{q_1} cos(\alpha)-\dot{q_2}$$

Since the wedge will be moving to the left, $\dot{q_2}$ will be negative.  We would expect $\dot{q_1}$ to be smaller as a result.  Which of those equations gives us that result?

If you plug a negative number into the first equation for $\dot{q_2}$, you are adding a negative number to the x-component, making it smaller.  That matches what we expect.

If you plug a negative number into the second equation for $\dot{q_2}$, you are subtracting a negative number from the x-component, which would make it larger.  That is the opposite of what we expect.

**Taylor's expression is the right one.**

I've found this sort of thing confusing before.  If you add the components, then the components are negative, you get the "opposite" result that you are expecting.

Comment: I see. So, it seems my confusion is about _when_ to take direction into account. I understood what Taylor meant when he said "we take the vector sum", it was just that I was taking the negative into account too soon (?). Is the idea, then, like you were saying, to create a formula with the mindset of "what would happen if I put a negative number in here" ?. Which is why, say, in this situation the (m) block would have a -ve potential energy because if we plugged in a -ve into that formula (which in this case would be higher up) the answer would be positive, which is what we expect?

Comment: Yeah, that's it.  It's just the sort of thing I always have to think about carefully, or I get mixed up.  I'm not understanding your potential energy comment, though.  Also, what is "-ve"?

Comment: Sorry, "-ve"="negative". Let us consider the potential energy of the block with mass (m). The potential component of the Lagrangian V(x) should be -mglsin(\alpha) where l is the length of the hypotenuse. This is because in the given coordinate system we need to define it like that in order to get a positive potential energy the higher off the ground the block is.

Comment: However, there are plenty of situations where you can't easily tell which way it goes until you plug the numbers. In my experience: unless I t's not obvious, don't sweat it. If you guessed wrong, you'll get a negative number, and that's fine. Just double check that all the signs are mutually consistent.